# how to select part of the row and pasting to form other file?

Tags: awk, copy-paste

I want you help me how to organize my data by cutting in the following way. I have the input data as below.

**input.file:**

```
1   2   1   0.6007  0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0   2   0.3073  0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
2   2   1   0.4022  0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0   2   0.5085  0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
3   2   1   0.0029  0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0   2   0.9078  0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
4   2   1   0.0692  0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0   2   0.8805  0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
```

My desired output file would look like this:

**out.file:**

```
1   2                               
        0.6007  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.3073  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
2   2                               
        0.4022  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.5085  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
3   2                               
        0.0029  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.9078  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
4   2                               
        0.0692  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.8805  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the brute force way using `awk` :

```
$ awk '
    {print $1"   "$2}
    {print "\t"$4"  "$3"   "$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}
    {print "\t"$12"  "$11"   "$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18}
  ' input.file
1   2
        0.6007  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.3073  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
2   2
        0.4022  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.5085  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
3   2
        0.0029  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.9078  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
4   2
        0.0692  1   0.1 0.3 0.2 0.7 0.7 0
        0.8805  2   0.1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.5
```

Here's a slightly more compact version that uses for loops to do the columns that are in series:

```
$ awk '
    {print $1"   "$2}
    {printf("\t%s  %s   ",$4,$3)}
    {for(i=5;i<=10;i++)printf("%s ",$i);print ""}
    {printf("\t%s  %s   ",$12,$11)}
    {for(i=13;i<=18;i++)printf("%s ",$i);print ""}
  ' input.file
```

Comment: Seems your awk-fu is strong young padawan!

Comment: @DravSloan - LOL, thanks for the laugh. It's something 8-)

Answer (score 2):

We're at it again slm :)

Similar mechanism in perl, from the command line:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[0]   $F[1]\n        $F[3]   $F[2]   @F[4..9]\n" .
    "        $F[11]   $F[10]   @F[12..17]\n"' inputfile
```

`-n` processes each line of `inputfile` as a loop. `-a` splits each line around the field separator (which defaults to space) and assigns it to the special array `@F` and `-e` passes these to the perl command specified (which simply prints the elements in the order required with spacing and newlines where required).

To put it in a perl script file:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -an 

print "$F[0]   $F[1]\n        $F[3]   $F[2]   @F[4..9]\n" .
     "        $F[11]   $F[10]   @F[12..17]\n";
```

Chmod the file (`chmod u+x perlscript`), then simply run `./perlscript inputfile`.

And if you need the output in a different file just put `> outputfile` at the end of the command (this is the same for the first example to use directly on the command line)

```
./perlscript inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: You know you love it 8-)

Comment: Tried it and it works for me!

Comment: @Drav Sloan, I have the following error massage     syntax error at -e line 1, near "."
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.

Comment: This is also how I run the code                    #!/usr/bin/perl -ane
'print "$F[0]    $F[1]\n           $F[3]  $F[2]   @F[4..9]\n" .
    "           $F[11]  $F[10]   @F[12..17]\n"' veginput

Comment: Odd, in which case, remove the `" . (new line) "` from the command, it shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: It was to be used from the command line :) So you just cut and paste it and replace the `inputfile` with the name of file you want to process.

Comment: I've added how to use it in a perl script :)

Comment: @DravSloan, It works perfect now. Thank you very much!!!